# how to implement authentication for encrypted data

Tags: authentication, encryption, hash, encryption-symmetric

if I have data that was encrypted using RC5 and I want to use authentication can I use a hash function? and which hash is the best, or shall I use a predetermined way between the sender and the receiver? if there is any other way to achieve this service, please help with any suggestions. thank you

Comment: You need to provide much more information about the use case.

Comment: after sending the encrypted information the receiver must verify that the information has not been altered (i.e. it was received as it was send without any changes) .

Comment: 1. Why not use HTTPS, everything in the connection is encrypted and authenticated, it is more secure than a home-made solution. 2. Why use RC5 and not AES? 3. For an example of authenticated encryption see [RNCryptor Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md). 4. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Comment: I've been reading about MD5 and other techniques but I don't know which one to choose and what is the most suitable way, do you have any reference having more info. about HTTPS  and how to use it to authenticate? about RC5 my supervisor told me to use it, why is it not secure?

Comment: Authentication of the cliet to the server or the server to the client? The server is authenticated by the server certificate. The client can aiuthenticate to the server with a shared secret (password or token).

Comment: I am assuming that correct authentication is not very important given that you are relying on YouTube videos. Who are you protecting against and what is the value of what is being protected?

Comment: I have a sender and a receiver the receiver wants to make sure that the information he received has not been altered by a third party

Comment: I'm simulating the encryption/decryption and the security services.

Comment: HTTPS ensures that the data has not been altered.

Comment: Essentially the minimum requirements to create your own security scheme is 5+ years of full-time supervised experience. HTTPS (and the underlying TLS and certificates) has been well vetted and understood, we have substantial confidence in it and that is why it should be deferred to if possible. Hopefully it is only your information that is at risk, not the user's information. Just for starters RC5 should not be used for new work and MD5 as well as SHA1 should also be avoided.

Comment: thank you for your replies and for your time